# No response EF Core migrations "Add-Migration" command

Tags: entity-framework, migration, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

Situation:

After a supposed corruption on my W10 notebook, I had to restore the system to a previous point. All my softwares were missing (including VS 2K17, SQL SERVER, Office etc). All my project files were untouched though.

After reinstalling them all I tried executing the following command:

Add-Migration 20180209 -verbose

Just to get back this:

More than one startup project found.
Using project '3 - Infrastructure\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context'.
Using startup project '3 - Infrastructure\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile C:\Users\FILENGA\Source\repos\Any.Gym\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\FILENGA.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --fx-version 2.0 "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.0.1\tools\netcoreapp2.0\ef.dll" migrations add 20180209 --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly C:\Users\FILENGA\Source\repos\Any.Gym\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context.dll --startup-assembly C:\Users\FILENGA\Source\repos\Any.Gym\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context.dll --project-dir C:\Users\FILENGA\Source\repos\Any.Gym\Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context\ --root-namespace Any.Gym.Infrastructure.Context

Any idea? I've already deleted bin an obj folders along the project and re-executed just to get back the same response

Already deleted "MIGRATION" folder too. No success.

If I switch to the wrong startupproject I do get the expected message:

No DbContext was found in assembly 'Any.Gym.API'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. It is an issue with EF.

Reference:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10926
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10298

Add this to Context class csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```