# Package manger console stuck after build

Tags: asp.net-core

I can not add migration. package manager console just builds project and then nothing happens.

```
PM> Add-Migration test
Build started...
Build succeeded.
//stucked here
```

and in the output window shows:

```
Build started...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 9:22 PM and took 00.142 seconds ==========
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: do you try migration for entityFramework?
if you are using entityFramework before using Add-Migration you should using Enable-Migration command at first.  @Zahra

Comment: I'm using asp net core and enitity framework core. It's enabled. It was working but, now it's not working.@narges

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710579/no-response-ef-core-migrations-add-migration-command)?

Comment: I tried it, and nothing happened. @XinranShen